# JSON-RPC libraries for java

Tags: java, json-rpc

I am looking for a json-rpc client library for java that will help with interprocess communication. I found json-rpc4j. Are there any other libraries that you can suggest? The josn-rpc 4j is not quite working with the inputstream and outputstream of java.

I found jsonrpc 4j client library. but it quite isn't working for me. so I want to see if any other library works for me .

Comment: Why does it need to be JSON, as opposed to "anything that lets you do RPC"?